# Change text color of AutocompleteSupportFragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-theme

I have a fragment that is used as AutocompleteSupportFragment to autocomplete location. I am using two themes. After selecting a place, the text is displayed black in light mode, but when shifted to dark mode, the color remains black only. I want that to change to white (i.e. @color/text).

XML code

```
<fragment
                    android:id="@+id/autocompletePickLoc"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pickUpIndicator"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPickup" />
```

HomeFragment

```
Places.initialize(requireContext(), getString(R.string.MAP_API));
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragmentPick = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.autocompletePickLoc);

        assert autocompleteSupportFragmentPick != null;
        autocompleteSupportFragmentPick.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
        autocompleteSupportFragmentPick.setLocationRestriction(RectangularBounds.newInstance(delhiBounds));
        autocompleteSupportFragmentPick.setText(currentAddress);
        autocompleteSupportFragmentPick.requireView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autocomplete);
```

R.drawable.autocomplete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/ternary"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/background"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>


</shape>
```

**Light Theme**

colors

```
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="primary">#8BC34A</color>
    <color name="primaryVariant">#559011</color>
    <color name="secondary">#337cff</color>
    <color name="secondaryVariant">#0850D0</color>
    <color name="ternary">#e8e8e8</color>
    <color name="text">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="hint">#858080</color>
```

theme

```
<style name="Theme.UserApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFC107</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#FF9800</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/text</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/text</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

**Dark Theme**

colors

```
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="background">#181818</color>
    <color name="primary">#64625A</color>
    <color name="primaryVariant">#26241E</color>
    <color name="secondary">#F49B20</color>
    <color name="secondaryVariant">#C97603</color>
    <color name="ternary">#262424</color>
    <color name="text">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="hint">#AEAEAE</color>
```

theme

```
<style name="Theme.UserApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/text</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/text</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/background</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Check these Screenshots -

Light theme:

[image: Light theme]

Dark theme:

[image: Dark Theme]

In the dark theme, the hint is visible and is white, but after selecting the place, it's black.

Comment: Can you add `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/text</item>` in your theme and let me know if it works or not?

Comment: @ganjaam No, it didn't work. The text is still black.